# Add multiple series with drilldown to multiple series in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/) in Vaadin.

```
$(function () {

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts multi-series drilldown'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click columns to drill down to single series. Click categories to drill down both.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '2010',
        data: [{
            name: 'Republican',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'republican-2010'
        }, {
            name: 'Democrats',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'democrats-2010'
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'other-2010'
        }]
    }, {
        name: '2014',
        data: [{
            name: 'Republican',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'republican-2014'
        }, {
            name: 'Democrats',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'democrats-2014'
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'other-2014'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'republican-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 4],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 1],
                ['South', 4]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'democrats-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 6],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 2],
                ['South', 4]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'other-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 2],
                ['West', 7],
                ['North', 3],
                ['South', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'republican-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 2],
                ['West', 4],
                ['North', 1],
                ['South', 7]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'democrats-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 4],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 5],
                ['South', 3]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'other-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 7],
                ['West', 8],
                ['North', 2],
                ['South', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
});
```

I am using the asynchronous Drilldown to generate the series:

```
chart.setDrilldownCallback(new DrilldownCallback() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6274915467357292767L;

    @Override
    public DataSeries handleDrilldown(DrilldownEvent event) {
        i++;
        return buildDataSeries(event.getItem());
    }
});
```

As you can see `handleDrilldown(DrilldownEvent event)` returns one DataSeries and I need a list.

Is there any way to add multiple series with drilldown in Vaadin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need a list of `DataSeries`. You should have enough information in the `DrilldownEvent` object to know which bar (republican/democrat/other;2010/2014) was selected. Knowing that, you can construct a single `DataSeries` which contains all four East, West, North, South values. As can be seen the link you submitted, each drilldown is contained within one series "Series 3".

```
String year = event.getSeries().getName() // 2010 or 2014
String party = event.getDataSeriesItem().getName() // Republican, Democrat or Other
```

Knowing that you can construct you DataSeries:

```
DataSeries series = new DataSeries();
series.add(new DataSeriesItem("East", a);
series.add(new DataSeriesItem("West", b);
series.add(new DataSeriesItem("North", c);
series.add(new DataSeriesItem("South", d);
// a, b, c, d depending on the year and party variables above
```

Comment: This is one DataSeries and I need more than one. My problem is not how to build the DataSeries, my problem is how to pass more than one in the `handleDrilldown()` method

Comment: You can't do it with Highcharts so you will not be able to do it with Vaadin Charts. In the Highcharts API you will see that each item in `series.data` can have only one `drilldown` id. This is why `handleDrilldown()` only returns a `DataSeries` and not a list of it. Can you maybe edit your post to explain in more details why you need a list of `DataSeries`, and why a single `DataSeries` is not enough?

Comment: In the example, if you click in Republican label for example, you can see two values for east, west, north and south. Each value (or column) is one DataSeries, and I don't know how to add more than one DataSeries when drilling down.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see, I had only clicked on the column and not on the label. You can set a breakpoint inside `handleDrilldown()` and if you go through it when you click on the "Republican" label then my guess is that it's a limitation in the Vaadin Charts framework...